# What is the most efficient method to conduct for hypothesis testing?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

To gather from the data whether the hypotheses I proposed are confirmed, I calculate the two means between different reform variables to see if the reform have influence on the performance indicators of the electricity generation sector. So I want to measure the significance of the difference between two sample means of our observation using t-statistic calculated as part of the t-test (i.e. as a scaled difference between two different means, where the absolute difference between them is rescaled using an estimate of the variability of the means). How do I start?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you provide some more information about what your issue is? Are you asking for help performing the t-test? Or are you wondering if rescaling the variables prior to the t-test will change its result (if you use each sample mean and variance to rescale each sample, it will)?

Comment: Thank Antoine for your prompt response. Anywell, this approach was used by Maria Vagliasindi and John Besant-Jones (2013) Power Market structure: Revisiting Policy options. I want to adopt the method, but I don't know how to go about it. I have conducted t-statistic for variables, but do not know how to scale the difference b/w two means, where the absolute difference is rescale using an estimate of the variability of the mean. such tests will be performed for each of the hypothesis.

Answer (score 3):

For those of you interested, I think the document mentioned in OP's comment is this [pdf](http://www-wds.worldbank.org/external/default/WDSContentServer/IW3P/IB/2013/03/22/000445729_20130322120523/Rendered/PDF/761790PUB0EPI00LIC00pubdate03014013.pdf). The analysis is on page 44, part of which was posted here as the question.

Now, to the question. What they did is likely an "independent sample t-test." To start, you'll need to have at least two columns of data, one is the dependent variable which is continuous in nature, and one is a dichotomous variable that indicates the grouping.

Once you have those ready, then based on the software you use, you can try searching for appropriate readings or videos online. Or ask your technical questions on another forum [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

If you're going to compute the t-statistics by hand, then you can find plenty of examples online by performing a [keyword-specific search](https://www.google.com/search?q=independent+sample+t-test).

---

In addition, the way Vagliasindi and Besant-Jones describe their analysis is not the most reader-friendly. I'd suggest you to consult a couple introductory statistics books, perhaps one for general statistics and one related to your field of interest.